# How to access data sent via next parameter in express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am running an express server and came across a middleware problem with passport authenticate which is something like this

```
passport.use('google', new GoogleStratergy({
    clientID:     "",
    clientSecret: "",
    callbackURL: "/Users/auth/google/callback",
    passReqToCallback   : true
}, (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    Users.findOne({ UserID: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
        if (err){
            return done(err);
        }
        if (!user){
            var User = new Users({});
            User.setPassword(Math.random().toString(36).substring(5));

            var jwt = User.generateJWT();

            User.save()
                .then(() => {
                    return done(null, User, jwt);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    return done(err);
                })
        }
        else {
            var jwt = user.generateJWT();
            return done(null, user, jwt);
        }
    });
  }
));
```

just now I don't know how to access the objects passed in the done function when using the middleware in another route like this.

```
router.get('/something', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res, next) => {
    // Now I need to access User and jwt object here passed with done()
    res.send("whatever");
})
```

Comment: One of the reasons I found about objects not getting passed is because passport calls lot of other functions before passing the flow to next middleware causing some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the req object? do this

```
router.get('/something', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.user)
    console.log(req.jwt)
    // Now I need to access User and jwt object here passed with done()
    res.send("whatever");
})
```

Comment: No, I tried that and it doesn't get passed in the req object